# xcode function-like macro syntax

Tags: xcode, macros

I have a problem in macro syntax. Here is my code:

```
#define DICT2(v1, k1, v2, k2) [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:v1, k1, v2, k2, nil]
#define NUM(number) [NSNumber numberWithInt:number]
```

which gives me the following syntax error:

```
Unexpected interface name 'NSDictionary': expected expression
Unexpected interface name 'NSNumber': expected expression
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You know with the simplified literals syntax Xcode now recognizes:

```
NSNumber *num = @1;
NSDictionary = @{ k1 : v1, k2 : v2};
```

So you don't need to use the macros.